# Micro SD card problems

Tags: storage

My Samsung 4s doesn't have enough storage to update. So the whole reason for my switch from apple to android was that I can add storage to it. Yet here I am I put the card in and reboot my phone and still no extra space to be found on my phone.... what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an SD card doesn't add space to your phone, it provides an additional path for storage.  Your phone has limited internal memory that can't be increased.  After adding the SD card, it should mount on its own.  After that, you should try moving some media or apps to the SD card to clear enough room on your phone to install your update.